# First use of “learnings”?

Tags: etymology

When was the word *learnings* first used as a noun, as a synonym for *lessons*?

Comment: I've never heard "learnings" before.  Do you have any sources or examples you can share?

Comment: @KristinaLopez I fully agree that I cringe when I hear it, for it sounds like annoying business jargon to me. But apparently this is a resurgent use of something long ago obsolete.

Comment: Related and semi-quasi-hemi-half-demi-duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/19227/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/91390/2085

Comment: After 26 years in the corporate world, I can confirm that "learning" instead of "lesson learned" is used all the time in that context, and has been for a decade or so. Personally, it does make me cringe as well, even if obsolete usage does give it legitimacy.

Answer (score 6):

The answer appears to be in 1483, at least in the plural.

The OED gives sense 2 of the verbal noun ***learning*** five different subsenses, of which at least the last (and perhaps others; it is subclear) is marked obsolete.  I include a few citations in the plural, with bold emphasis mine.

> **2**. What is learnt or taught:
>
> - **a.** a lesson, instruction;
>
>   - 1483 Caxton *G. de la Tour* cxxxvii. M vij, — The thre enseygnementes or **lernynges** whiche Cathon gaf to his sone.
>   - 1611 Shaks. *Cymb*. **i.** i. 43 — The king..Puts to him all the **Learnings** that his time Could make him the receiuer of.
> - **b.** information or direction;
> - **c.** the ‘teaching’ of a person; a doctrine; also, a doctrine or maxim in law;
>
>   - 1549 Coverdale, etc. *Erasm. Par. Rom.* 34 — To expounde unknowen **learnynges**.
>   - 1560 Pilkington *Aggeus* C ij (Matt. xv. 9), — Teaching **learninges** which are the commaundementes of men.
>   - A. 1626 Bacon *Max. & Uses Com. Law Pref.* (1636) 2 — Particular and positive **learnings** of lawes doe easily decline from a good temper of justice.
> - **d.** a branch of learning; a science;
>
>   - 1570 Billingsley *Euclid* **xi**. xi. 315 — It is no rare thing in all **learninges**..to haue one thing more generall then an other.
>   - 1605 Bacon *Adv. Learn*. **i**. vi. §13 (1873) 49 — He did send his divine truth into the world, waited on with other **learnings**.
>   - 1613 Sir H. Finch *Law* (1636) 6 — The rules of Reason are of two sorts; some taken from forreigne **learnings**, both diuine and humane.
> - **e.** an acquirement. *Obs*.

My personal impression is that the modern use sounds like annoying business jargon or non-native speaker use, and I would not use it myself.

Answer (score 3):

OED has three citations for *learning* meaning *lesson*, but it notes it's obsolete.

> †**2.** What is learnt or taught:
> **a.** a lesson, instruction.
>
> > 1362   Langland *Piers Plowman* A. i. 174   That nis no treuthe of trinite but..a leornyng for lewed men, the latere forte dele.
> > 1484   Caxton tr. G. de la Tour-Landry *Bk. Knight of Tower* (1971) cxxxvii. 183 (*heading*)    The thre enseygnementes or lernynges whiche Cathon gaf to his sone.
> > a1616   Shakespeare *Cymbeline* (1623) i. i. 43   The king..Puts to him all the Learnings that his time Could make him the receiuer of.

The **latest** citation is Shakepeare when he wrote it in 1616 (published 1623).

Comment: I don’t see a dagger-of-doom at the front of my OED2 entry, just the *Obs.* marker for the 2e sense. Is yours from the online OED3? I agree that the *Piers Plowman* citation is a count-noun use.  Hm, why isn’t it *Piers Ploughman*? Was Langland North American? :)

Comment: It's online, but "This entry has not yet been fully updated (first published 1902)." *Plowman* was variously spelled in ME, including *plouman*; Langland's text includes " Pieres þe ploughman"